# Panorama-like XAML layout with state and transitions

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-phone-8

In my app I'd like to have a page layout as shown on this picture:
[image]

It has two content blocks (depicted as plain and shaded rectangles) and two states. In normal (1st) state plain block takes all the screen and is fully visible while shaded is hidden behind screen. In 2nd state shaded block is fully visible and also a small part of plain block is on screen, the rest of it is hidden.

I'd also like to have a nice transition from one state to another. I understand I'd probably need to use ViewStates for this. What I don't understand it what XAML control should I use to represent content blocks. So this is the question: what XAML controls would allow me to express this layout as elegantly and concisely as possible?

Comment: Also, I actually don't want panorama itself because it would show a bit of shaded rectangle by default and it will be horizontally scrollable. I don't want either of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a grid with 2 rows. A pivot control with your 2 states in each pivot item in first row and your fixed content in second row.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Background="Red">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <phone:Pivot Margin="0,-24,0,0">
        <phone:PivotItem Background="Blue">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Transition content 1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:PivotItem>
        <phone:PivotItem Background="Brown">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Transition content 2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Fixed content" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Swiping on the top box will animate as the standard pivot animation.

If you don't want the user to be able to flick and rather control the two states programmatically then you can simply add `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on the root pivot control then set the `SelectedIndex` on the pivot to switch between states.